# What sort of character is this ()

Tags: fonts, unicode, special-characters

I recently came across [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/revisions/137558/2) answer on [Sci-Fi Stack Exchange](http://scifi.stackexchange.com). It appears to be written in a font designed to look like hard-to-read, old fashioned handwriting. As such, to make it easier to read, I copy/pasted it into gedit (a text editor that does not support formatting — like Notepad). To my surprise, the strange formatting stayed. Upon further inspection (i.e., Googling the most strange looking characters, noticing the year appears to be written partially normally) I came to the conclusion that they are a set of strange letter-like characters in Unicode.

My question has two parts:

1. Am I correct about what these characters are?
2. If so, why does Unicode contain extra characters that appear to serve no purpose other than that of fonts?

Comment: http://unicode-table.com/en/1D4B2/

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It is the Unicode character [U+1D4E6](http://unicode.scarfboy.com/?s=U%2B1D4E6) – Mathematical Bold Script Capital W.

The letter is from the Unicode block ‘[Mathematical Alphanumeric Symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_Alphanumeric_Symbols)’. It is used by mathematicians to distinguish different objects, e.g., different sets. In Word, the character is accessible by *Insert Equation → Symbols → Scripts.*

As the character set looks kind of ancient, you can of course write regular text in it as well, e.g., a Sci-Fi story.

Comment: Note that using such characters to write regular text is strongly discouraged and causes issues in terms of searchability, portability, and accessibility.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Firefox seems to be able to search for it [which is more than can be said for stuff like IPA small caps that some people use]

Comment: @Random832: … not if you turn on *match case.*

Comment: @Wrzlprmft I forgot that I was in chrome instead of firefox anyway. But it still proves my real point, which is that the inability to search for it is a technical problem to be solved [just as it was for curly quotes] rather than an insurmountable fundamental fact.

Comment: @Random832: I disagree. If I search with *match case* (or similar verbatim search options), I want to find exactly the Unicode characters I enter into the search field – that’s what such options are for. For example, if I have a properly encoded mathematical document, I may want to search for all instances of the mathematical symbol , but not the capital letter *W.* Your “solution” would break this. The only alternative would be to offer the user a detailed inventory of options, as to what types of Unicode characters shall be equated by the search, which would be overwhelming for most.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Has it ever bothered you that curly quotes are matched when you type straight quotes [and vice versa] in the search? Does it bother you now? Chrome doesn't even have "match case".

Comment: @Random832: I elaborated my comment in detail in [this Q&A](http://superuser.com/q/1160295/203639).

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Nothing you said there was really relevant to what I asked, which is whether there is any technical (there's not) or UX (you claim this but haven't explained it, there or here) reason that a search for a letter should not successfully find most variants of that letter (not cyrillic/greek lookalikes, but any small caps / mathematical / fullwidth / circled variants that truly are still the same letter (i.e. the same ones that are successfully found _now_ without "match case"). Why would you need a "detailed inventory"? In what scenario will anyone ever need anything but exact/inexact?