# What kind of special character is this:  ?

Tags: unicode, special-characters

I see someone wrote this comment in a Facebook post:

> 

[image: How does it look like on my computer]

...and I'm quickly interested in finding what kind of character is that, so I googled it, but the search results return the ordinary text as "heavens gate", not the stylized one.

What kind of special character is that? How to write that character and what is the unicode number range for that stylized character from A to Z (and for number too, if exist)?

Comment: https://coolsymbol.com/cool-fancy-text-generator.html

Comment: Related: [Why shouldn’t I use Unicode characters to simulate typographic styles (such as small caps or script)?](https://superuser.com/q/1160295/203639)

Comment: Could you please include a screenshot of what it looks like for you? Not every gets the same result, for me it's just question marks in boxes

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Those are characters from the [“Mathematical Alphanumeric Symbols” block](https://unicode-table.com/en/blocks/mathematical-alphanumeric-symbols/). For example, the :

> Mathematical Bold Italic Small E
>   U+1D486

:

> Mathematical Bold Script Small T
>   U+1D4FD

In mathematics, you often see those kind of “script” letters.

Comment: Yeah, just now I looked up that character in a unicode lookup website and it is described as mathematical bold script.

Comment: Although, actually, I've never seen lower-case scripted letters used in mathematics (which is basically what I do for a living).

Comment: @DavidRicherby I think I remember the styled `` from AP physics in highschool

Answer (score 39):

There are many Unicode-lookup websites; the one I use is [Uniview](https://r12a.github.io/uniview/) by Richard Ishida of the W3C.

If you paste your text into the box on that page and click on the down arrow, it shows you each character:

[image: screenshot from Uniview]

…and you can click on each character for more information. There are also a lot of other features; you can explore for yourself.

The characters in “ ” are:

- [U+1D4F1 MATHEMATICAL BOLD SCRIPT SMALL H](https://codepoints.net/U+1D4F1), encoded in UTF-8 as `F0 9D 93 B1`
- [U+1D486 MATHEMATICAL BOLD ITALIC SMALL E](https://codepoints.net/U+1D486), encoded in UTF-8 as `F0 9D 92 86`
- [U+1D4EA MATHEMATICAL BOLD SCRIPT SMALL A](https://codepoints.net/U+1D4EA), encoded in UTF-8 as `F0 9D 93 AA`
- [U+1D4FF MATHEMATICAL BOLD SCRIPT SMALL V](https://codepoints.net/U+1D4FF), encoded in UTF-8 as `F0 9D 93 BF`
- [U+1D486 MATHEMATICAL BOLD ITALIC SMALL E](https://codepoints.net/U+1D486), encoded in UTF-8 as `F0 9D 92 86`
- [U+1D4F7 MATHEMATICAL BOLD SCRIPT SMALL N](https://codepoints.net/U+1D4F7), encoded in UTF-8 as `F0 9D 93 B7`
- [U+1D4FC MATHEMATICAL BOLD SCRIPT SMALL S](https://codepoints.net/U+1D4FC), encoded in UTF-8 as `F0 9D 93 BC`
- [U+0020 SPACE](https://codepoints.net/U+0020), encoded in UTF-8 as `20`
- [U+1D4F0 MATHEMATICAL BOLD SCRIPT SMALL G](https://codepoints.net/U+1D4F0), encoded in UTF-8 as `F0 9D 93 B0`
- [U+1D4EA MATHEMATICAL BOLD SCRIPT SMALL A](https://codepoints.net/U+1D4EA), encoded in UTF-8 as `F0 9D 93 AA`
- [U+1D4FD MATHEMATICAL BOLD SCRIPT SMALL T](https://codepoints.net/U+1D4FD), encoded in UTF-8 as `F0 9D 93 BD`
- [U+1D486 MATHEMATICAL BOLD ITALIC SMALL E](https://codepoints.net/U+1D486), encoded in UTF-8 as `F0 9D 92 86`